# Condition for incorrect password selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

My code. I enter my login and password in the "userId" and "password" fields. And I would like to write a condition that will check when you hit the "Submit" button or it is possible to login to the system. If "userId" and "password" are correct, then when you press the "Submit" button a new page loads and the next part of the code is posted. But I would like to add a condition when the user gives a bad password. Then, after pressing the "Submit" button, the message "Bad login information" appears on the page. Can anyone help me write such a condition?

```
 for(int i =0;i<userName.size();i++){
        driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys(userName.get(i));
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password.get(i));
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Submit")).click();
```

// Here load new page

```
           // change password
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='_id9']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(6000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


            // new password
            String pwd = RandomStringUtils.random( 15, upper+smaller+number+character);
            System.out.println("New password: " + pwd);
            driver.findElement(By.id("newPassword")).sendKeys(pwd);
            Thread.sleep(6000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // confirm password
            driver.findElement(By.id("confirmPassword")).sendKeys(pwd);
            System.out.println("Confirm password: " + pwd);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Can I request you to work with the solution provided by our community experts on your previous questions​ and close the discussion threads before you ask a new question? Thanks

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. There is tons of info on SO and the web to help you do what you are asking. Part of learning is actually taking the time to attempt to do what you are asking BEFORE asking others to do your work for you. Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

after clicking Submit button; you can check whether this element is present on your page or not :  `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='_id9']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a"));`

if it is that means new page was loaded as login was successful or else it was a bad login.

you can do so after clicking submit button try following:

**UPDATE**

```
List<WebElement> myElemnt = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='_id9']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a"));

loginSuccessful(myElemnt);
```

// implementation of loginSuccessful() function:

```
public boolean loginSuccessful(WebElement element){
    try{
        element;
        return true;
       }

    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Bad Login Information!!");
        return false;
       }

}
```

**OLD**

```
  String beforeTitle = driver.getTitle();

  //put your Click Submit Button code here

  String afterTitle = driver.getTitle();

  if(beforeTitle.equals(afterTitle)){

    System.out.println("Bad Login Information!!");

   }
```

Comment: It's looks OK but if the element not exist the default 30 sec timeout will cause wait. You can create your own function with find element (and not elements) ant catch exception for faster code

Comment: Actually it works what you wrote. Thank you. But as he wrote @ Hezi Israeli. If there is no such item, it is waiting for 30s, could you help how to do it so that it does not wait so much time?

Comment: And can you somehow reduce the 30 timeout for the first case? Because the title on both sides is the same :(